# Can't scroll down on iPhone 6

Tags: ios, iphone, scroll, responsive-design

my client has an iPhone 6 and can't scroll down on a particular page that has a form in an "overlay" over the rest of the page.
It works fine in iPhone 5c, so I am a little confused why?
Here is the page: http://www.ingleandrhode.co.uk/appointment-form/

Many thanks
Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have load the url in the webView and in iPhone 6 scrolling is smooth. Just added webview to my viewController and added autolayout constraint trailing, leading, top & bottom space. Check screenshots.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks Uttam, very good to see.  What simulator are you using for this?

Comment: Version 8.1 (550.3). Check in above screenshots.

Comment: One last thing, if you go here http://www.ingleandrhode.co.uk/ and click "make an appointment" in the footer, can you scroll the form that slides in on iPhone 6?

Comment: Thanks Uttam, appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi, my client is saying it slides fine until he taps to edit a field then he loses the ability to scroll?

Comment: @DaveReeder - check the uploaded screenshot, with keyboard shown also scrolling works fine :)